# Clear Selection in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

Is there any way to delete all content in a selection of tasks without looping?

```
'Something like
Sub Select_Column() 
   ViewApply Name:="&Gantt Chart" 
   SelectColumn Column:=4, Extend:=False
   Selection.Clearcontents
End Sub
```

Any hint, link or explanation would be useful.

Comment: You misspelled Contents,  change `Selection.Clearcontetns` for `Selection.ClearContents`

Comment: it doesn't matter since ms project doesn't support ClearContents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EditClear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.editclear) is the method used in Project to clear the contents of the selection.

```
Sub Select_Column()
   ViewApply Name:="&Gantt Chart"
   SelectColumn Column:=4, Extend:=False
   EditClear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Set_Value_Selection(mySelection As Selection, myValue As Variant)
    Dim myTask As task
    Dim columnID As Long
    
    If Not (mySelection.tasks Is Nothing) Then
        Set myTask = mySelection.tasks.item(1)
        columnID = mySelection.FieldIDList.item(1)
        
        myTask.SetField spaltenID, myValue
        FillDown
    End If
End Sub
```